# Prolog list manipulation

Tags: list, prolog

I have a question and need someone to correct me:

`store(wyoming, [evan, sandra], [storybook, fiction, general]).`
`store(brooklyn, [haas, maria], [fiction, schoolbook, religion]).`
`store(oakland, [rich, walker, dina, vince], [storybook, schoolbook, fiction]).`

if i consult `?-locations(storybook).` the answer must return true because storybook available at more than one store. i write my predicate like this:

```
locations(Book) :- store(_, [_], [Books]), member(Book, Books).
```

when i consult, i will return false no matter what type of book i enter. how to solve this?

Comment: Try `store(_, _, Books)` instead of `store(_, [_], [Books])`. `[Books]` will only match a list with a single atom and instantiate `Books` with that single atom. And `[_]` will also only match a list with a single atom rather than any list. Both of these will cause a mis-match against all of your facts.

Comment: it return true every time the answer match. e.g, for storybooks, the "true" answer appear 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying mbratch suggestion, you still need to check when a `Book` is available at more than one store. The easy way, inefficient because if 'analyzes' all the DB:

```
locations(Book) :-
   findall(Book, (store(_,_,Books), memberchk(Book, Books)), L),
   length(L, N), N > 1.
```

We can make it less verbose:

```
locations(Book) :-
   findall(_, (store(_,_,Books), memberchk(Book, Books)), [_,_|_]).
```

Note I used memberchk/2 instead of member/2. It's faster and, as a side effect, avoids answering true in the case where there is only a store matching, but with the book present more than once.

To avoid scanning the entire database, a join will do:

```
locations(Book) :-
   store(X,_,BooksX), memberchk(Book,BooksX),
   store(Y,_,BooksY), Y \= X, memberchk(Book,BooksY),
   !.
```

The final cut prevents multiple useless answers for the same `Book`.

Comment: can you explain this line sir:                               findall(_, (store(_,_,Books), memberchk(Book, Books)), [_,_|_]).       especially this part---> [_,_|_]

Comment: simple unification: `[_,_|_]` matches *any* list with length>1